# Not able to login using request library in Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, basic-authentication

I am trying to open this [website](https://www.handy.com/login), and access the dashboard's information using `requests` library in python. This is kind of webscraping but the issue is I am not able to login. I tried bunch of different methods to post my login credentials but nothing is working so far.

Website - https://www.handy.com/login

Login HTML - `<input autofocus="autofocus" class="string email required" id="user_session_email" name="user_session[email]" required="required" size="50" type="email">`

Password HTML - `<input class="password required" id="user_session_password" name="user_session[password]" required="required" size="50" type="password">`

Code:

First I tried to use the name attribute of both the username and password

```
import requests
url = "https://www.handy.com/login"
payload = {"user_session[email]": "email or username", "user_session[password]": "password"}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print r.status_code
print r.reason
```

Also tried with using id attribute of both `username and password` but the issue is same. Status code is `500` and reason is `Internal Server Error`. I know how to create persistent sessions but will appreciate if you can help me to login in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, when authentication is required and a session must be maintained for further requests, the requests.session object is the intended way to do so.

This involves creating a session object and using that to send your POST requests.

session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, data=payload)

Another issue you're going to have is that you're not sending the same payload as your browser would (or, more importantly, as the server expects) and that's what the internal server error is indicating.

If you're using Firefox you can open the network monitor window with Ctrl-Shift-Q, select the POST request that the browser made to send your login details and go to the 'params' tab where you will see something like this:

[image]

So what you need to do initially is use the session object to make a `GET` request to the login page. From the HTML you just received from this request you need to parse the `authenticity_token`. Then you can use this token along with the email and password to make the POST request that authenticates to the site.